# Bash - Replace random text between commas

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, replace

I'm struggling to find a way to replace a random text between the **second** and **third** occurence commas on Linux bash.
The original text looks like this:

```
RANDOMTEXT,RANDOMTEXT, >RANDOMTEXT< ,RANDOMTEXT,RANDOMTEXT
```

The bold string is what I wanted to replace.
I've tried various things with sed and awk but nothing worked.

Comment: please provide [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). we are not supposed to guess what is your input and what you expect.

Comment: It is really like this. The only clue I have is that the text I need to replace is between the second and third commas. The replacing text is also random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
awk -F, '{ OFS=","; $3 = "Text to replace"; print }'
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked as expected! That was more simple than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/RANDOMTEXT/SOME_NEW_TEXT/3'
```

You can specify which occurence you want to replace with a number at the end of the substitute expression.

Answer (score 0):

You do something like that it not the best solution but you can inspired it

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=','
j=0
for i in $(echo "RANDOMTEXT,RANDOMTEXT,RANDOMTEXT,RANDOMTEXT,RANDOMTEXT"); do
  j=$(($j+1));
  if [ $j -eq 3 ]; then
    printf "nop,";
  fi
  printf "$i,"
done
```